# Finding if a number is a power of another number recursivly

Tags: java, recursion

Consider this code

```
public static boolean isPower(int x, int n) {

    if (x == 1)
        return (n == 1);

    int pow = 1;
    while (pow < n)
        pow = pow * x;
        return (pow == n);
}
```

The goal is to find if the number x is a power of the number n.I've come up with this algorithm,and it works.I'd like to solve it recursivly as well.I read through the linked post someone put in the coments(https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/279004/general-way-to-convert-a-loop-while-for-to-recursion-or-from-a-recursion-to-a)

I tried to replicate,or use the pattern that was provided in the answers.

First I tried to identify what my header,condition loop and tail was.

```
public static boolean isPower(int x, int n) {

    if (x == 1)//header
        return (n == 1);//header

    int pow = 1;//header
    while (pow < n)//condition
        pow = pow * x;//loop
        return (pow == n);//tail
}
```

Now I tried to apply the pattern;

```
public static boolean isPower_recursive(int x,int n) {
    if(x == 1)
        return (n==1);
    return isPower_recursion( x, n, 1);

    }
    public static boolean isPower_recursion(int x,int n, int pow) {
    if( 1 > n) {
        return (pow == n);
    }
    pow = pow * x;
    return isPower_recursion(x,n,pow);

}
```

This only works for the case when both x and n are one,in every other case I get a Stackoverflow error.The compiler says the error happens at the return statement in the isPower_recursive method,which leads me to think that i am not calculating this right.Some insight would be great.

Comment: You should do some **research**, e.g. a *web search* for [`loop using recursion`](https://www.google.com/search?q=loop+using+recursion) leads to informative articles like "[Replace Iteration with Recursion](https://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceIterationWithRecursion.html)".

Comment: See also this excellent answer over on our [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) sister site: [General way to convert a loop (while/for) to recursion or from a recursion to a loop?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/279006/202153)

Comment: That second like is actually pretty helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem.I applied the patter wrong,it should look like this.

```
public static boolean isPower_recursive(int x,int n) {
    if(x == 1)
        return (n==1);
    return isPower_recursion( x, n, 1);
 
    }
    public static boolean isPower_recursion(int x,int n, int pow) {
    if( pow >= n) {
        return (pow == n);
    }
    pow = pow * x;
    return isPower_recursion(x,n,pow);
 
}
```